# How can I get WPF go fullscreen

Tags: c#, wpf

when I click the btnFullScreen it doesn't go full screen, but when I resize the mainWindow and then click btnFullScreen it goes full screen, how can I make it go full screen without resizing it first?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question, add code/details instead of images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557

Answer (score 1):

is there any specific reason why you are setting WindowState, WindowStyle twice?

Just use

```
mainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
mainWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
```

once And **`Kaboom!!!`** You are Done.

Comment: didn't work. maybe because my cursor like selected a panel or something, and I have to select the mainWindow first before clicking btnFullScreen?

Comment: No, I don't think so that you have to select mainwindow to make it work.